# Haskell: Compare two lists and display double elements

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to program with Haskell, but I can't figure out one of my needs.

What I need:
A function to compare two given lists and display the double elements (elements that are in both lists).

Unfortunately I can't find anything helpfull on internet.

Anybody that could help or give me a kick in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

```
Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
[a] `intersect` [a]
```

Comment: Really? You can't find anything? What have you tried? What mathematical operation might be useful here?

Comment: intersect, but I can't get it to work in a function. (I am a beginner in Haskell)

Comment: We can tell you're a beginner. I assume this is an assignment. There's a general expectation (at least, *I* expect it) that you've tried first and tell us what you have tried. What do you mean by 'can't get it to work in a function'? Again, what have you tried? Show us your code!

Answer (score 4):

A function which would take two lists and yield a list of elements which occur in both input lists would also require the lists to be comparable for equality. So my first guess is that the signature is something like

```
Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

If you [feed this signature to Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Eq+a+%3D%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) you'll find that the [`intersect`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3Aintersect) function does what you want:

```
Prelude Data.List> [5,7,9,8,1,3] `intersect` [3,8,10,4,7,11]
[7,8,3]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I found something like this, but it has to be a function that I can use on any given list.

Comment: @user2021386 I just extended my answer to explain how I found this function, i.e. how you can use [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to find functions based on the signature you need.

Comment: Ah ok... So I have to define this signature to the function. And compare the two lists with intersect? Like in the code on my edited question?

Comment: @user2021386 I think it would be more fruitful if you followed the advice given in the comments to your question and explain what you tried so far (and why you tried it) and how that failed.

Comment: No, you don't have to include the type signature for `intersect` in _your_ code. The reason the Frerich mentioned the type signature is to show how you can find a function that you suspect exists but you don't know it's name. As for how you use it, Frerich gave you an example.